# How getDOM() works in Angular 2 specs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, angular, jasmine

How does `getDOM()` from `@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_adapter` actually work in specs?

It looks like [in some specs](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.4/modules/%40angular/core/test/dom/dom_adapter_spec.ts#L16-L24) `getDOM()` refers to some detached root element, similar to AngularJS `$rootElement`:

```
  var el1 = el('<div>a</div>');
  var el2 = el('<div>b</div>');
  getDOM().appendChild(el2, getDOM().firstChild(el1));
  expect(getDOM().childNodes(el2).length).toBe(2);
```

And in bundled [Jasmine matchers](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.4/modules/%40angular/platform-browser/testing/matchers.ts#L179) `getDOM()` magically refers to the same element:

```
    function(actual: any /** TODO #???? */, className: any /** TODO #???? */) {
      return {
        pass: getDOM().hasClass(actual, className) == !isNot,
        get message() {
          return `Expected ${actual.outerHTML} ${isNot ? 'not ' : ''}
                  to contain the CSS class "${className}"`;
        }
      };
    };
```

I was about to build some Chai assertions for convenience, but this makes me think that I'm missing something important about how Angular 2 behaves in unit tests.

What is going on there? How `getDOM()` context is being set? What is this context? Can there be only one context at time? Should `getDOM()` be used in production code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not import from `.../src/...` of a dependency, because this is considered private implementation of that package.

`DomAdapter` is for Angular2-internal use only.

It was exported as public for a while but was remove from the public API a while ago, this is why several answers suggest using it.

Comment: So I should ignore the reasons why internal matchers refer to it and just stick to regular DOM, shouldn't I?

Comment: Exactly. If you want full abstraction from the DOM (which is what `DomAdapter` usually is used for) you need to implement a custom `Renderer` but this isn't well documented yet.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will take a closer look at Renderer.